# Azure: Web Application Firewall Policy was not found

Tags: terraform

I have a simple data source block to retrieve a WAF policy resource but it doesn't find the resource. If I comment out the data block there is no problem. The WAF policy created by terraform can be applied and destroyed.

```
data "azurerm_web_application_firewall_policy" "example" {
name = "a205555-az-waf-policy"
resource_group_name = "eastus2-204161-platform-resources"

}

output "azurerm_web_application_firewall_policy" {
value = data.azurerm_web_application_firewall_policy.example.id

}
```

When I try to get the resource data I get error:

```
│ Error: Error: Web Application Firewall Policy "a205555-az-waf-policy" was not found
│   with data.azurerm_web_application_firewall_policy.example,
│   on output.tf line 40, in data "azurerm_web_application_firewall_policy" "example":
│   40: data "azurerm_web_application_firewall_policy" "example" {
│
```

I've tried removing the resource from tfstate, importing the resource, deleting and recreating it, upgrading the provider in case there was a bug. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure `azurerm_web_application_firewall_policy` can be a data source in Terraform?

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/web_application_firewall_policy

Comment: this might sound stupid but have you tried running `terraform fmt` and `terraform validate` before `terraform plan/apply`?

Comment: Yes they both come back ok

Comment: Hello @PaulDawson, may I know if you are using resource block and data block in the same file ? as per this `If I comment out the data block there is no problem. The WAF policy created by terraform can be applied and destroyed.`